# Phalcon Application sending "No data received" on production, but not localhost

Tags: php, phalcon

I am writing a Phalcon PHP website on windows and on my local server everything works as specified. When the base url is reached, it forwards to my public folder with .htaccess and loads index.php. The contents of index.php are below.
It should be noted that almost all contents in index.php below are from the official Phalcon documentation page.

```
<?php

echo "TEST TEST DEST";

use \Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher;

try {

    //Register an autoloader
    $loader = new \Phalcon\Loader();
    $loader->registerDirs(array(
        '../app/controllers/',
        '../app/models/'
    ))->register();

    //Create a DI
    $di = new Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault();

    //Setup the view component
    $di->set('view', function(){
        $view = new \Phalcon\Mvc\View();
        $view->setViewsDir('../app/views/');
        return $view;
    });

    $di->set(
    'dispatcher',
    function() use ($di) {
        $eventsManager = $di->getShared('eventsManager');
        $eventsManager->attach(
            'dispatch:beforeException',
            function($event, $dispatcher, $exception) {
                switch ($exception->getCode()) {
                    case Dispatcher::EXCEPTION_HANDLER_NOT_FOUND:
                    case Dispatcher::EXCEPTION_ACTION_NOT_FOUND:
                        $dispatcher->forward(
                            array(
                                'controller' => 'error',
                                'action' => 'error404',
                            )
                        );
                        return false;
                        break; // for checkstyle
                    default:
                        $dispatcher->forward(
                            array(
                                'controller' => 'error',
                                'action' => 'error404',
                            )
                        );
                        return false;
                        break; // for checkstyle
                }
            }
        );
        $dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
        $dispatcher->setEventsManager($eventsManager);
        return $dispatcher;
    },
    true
);

    //Setup a base URI so that all generated URIs include the "tutorial" folder
    $di->set('url', function(){
        $url = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Url();
        $url->setBaseUri('/');
        return $url;
    });

    //Handle the request
    $application = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Application($di);

    echo $application->handle()->getContent();

} catch(\Phalcon\Exception $e) {
     echo "PhalconException: ", $e->getMessage();
}
```

This then redirects the page to the index controller and the indexAction as specified by the default Phalcon behavior. On localhost this displays my index.html page perfectly as specified.

The problem is that when I load it to my production server, that is CentOS, the index.php file instead returns No Data Received when the following line is run.

```
echo $application->handle()->getContent();
```

I have no idea what the problem could be and am fairly new to Phalcon and PHP in general so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the logs? Maybe some error occurred regarding the different (possibly) environments you are running the code - the production and development machines. Different versions/configurations? Log output would be helpful.

Comment: As far as I understand it, to get the logs from Phalcon you must set them up manually, but the problem is that I don't know what I'm looking for so I wouldn't be able to log anything. I already have try/catch blocks to catch exceptions and none are being thrown so how would you suggest I proceed?

Comment: As far it concerns php there are errors and exceptions: `Exceptions` can be thrown and caught using the try..catch, however, `Errors` cannot be caught thus different mechanisms like `set_error_handler` (also `set_exception_handler`) were made to handle this properly. Also, some of the errors are recoverable (script execution continues) and unrecoverable (script execution stopped). It may be last case: there may be an unrecoverable error in your script.

Comment: The other difficulty is that the server I am using for production is property of my schools CS department I and I can't even get access to the Apache logs due to user restrictions. I'm going to try a couple things with somebody that has root access tomorrow to help evaluate the problem. I'll also try to set up some error handling today and see if that helps. If I figure it out I'll be sure to post what the problem was. Thanks for your suggestions @sitilge!

Comment: Sure, no problems. Please, ping me back about the status/escalation of this issue.